# What does it mean on a 10-K balance sheet when a field is blank for a single year?

Tags: corporation, balance-sheet

I am looking at a [corporate balance sheet in a 10-K for Chipotle](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1058090/000105809018000018/cmg-20171231x10k.htm#Item_8) and the line for `Long term investments` is $125b for 2016, but blank for 2017.

What does it mean when a company doesn't list this info for a single year? That it doesn't exist, or it is unknown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be pedantic, it's not "blank", is it a hyphen (-), which it typical accounting notation for zero.

So it means that they had sold (or written off) all of their long term investments in 2017.